# How can I compile a plugin for different upstream versions with Maven?

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, maven-central

I'm writing a data source plugin for Spark, which has a different API in 2.X and 3.X. I've taken the plunge to refactor out the version specific parts, and ended up with a tree like:

```
src/
  main/
    java/
      app/
        common/ # no dependency on spark
        spark/ # code compatible with both 2.X and 3.X
        adaptor_v24/ # 2.4 shim over classes in "common"
        adaptor_v30/ # 3.0 shim over classes in "common"
```

And a POM with a spark24 and spark30 profile to choose the appropriate Spark deps & include the correct `adaptor_vXX` version.

Now I'd like to publish the two versions of the plugin to Maven Central so users can get the correct version of their Spark installation. (loading the 2.x plugin into spark3's classpath and vice-versa causes an explosion since the appropriate interfaces aren't there). I think the right way is to publish w/a different artifactId suffix like "app-spark2"/"app-spark3", but from what I've seen, Maven really doesn't want you to alter the artifactId dynamically, so I've been doing a sed against the POM directly before I publish.

Is this the best I can do with Maven, or am I missing some feature/plugin that would let me handle this natively? I know, for example, sbt supports something similar to build/publish against multiple Scala runtimes, but that's the most similar thing I know to my problem.

Comment: you mean like ["maven classifier"](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploying-with-classifiers.html)?

Comment: @xerx593 It looks like I can upload jars w/different to maven, but Spark doesn't have any way to load them, it interprets the coordinate as "1.0.1-SNAPSHOT-spark3" instead of pulling the component out

Comment: ...wait, this was the "deployment side", on usage/client/dependency side, you would also provide (profile/environment based) `<dependency>...<classifier/>...</dependency>` ... [ref](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html)

Comment: "pulling the component out" - I am not sure what else is needed/the details of your assembly, but the consistent usage of classifier will bring you the "classified jar"(i assume jar from default dependency."type"(see above link)) ...into (scoped) classpath

Comment: Sorry, I meant pulling the "classifier component" out -- but in any case, yes, this is on the client side, but the user doesn't use a POM, they give spark a maven coordinate and spark downloads the packages (+deps) using the ivy resolver. (see spark.jars.packages at http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html). Spark doesn't understand classifiers, so trying to use multiple classifiers doesn't work